# Pysprak Dataframe to Python list Variable column name access

Tags: python, list, pyspark

My code is something like this:

```
for i in uniqueProduct_list:
  s3_df = channel_Result_8_df.filter((f.col("product") == i.product) & (f.col("S") == 3))
  s3_list =  s3_df.rdd.map(lambda x: x).collect()
  for j in month_list:
    print(s3_list[0].Gender)
    break
  break
```

This code is working fine when in line 5 I have a fixed column name, However, when I am trying to replace this with another column name whose name is not fixed e.g. 202005 (this column name keep changing and I am accessing it through another list (month_list, in line 4), so I am changing my code like this (only line 5 is changed):

```
    for i in uniqueProduct_list:
      s3_df = channel_Result_8_df.filter((f.col("product") == i.product) & (f.col("S") == 3))
      s3_list =  s3_df.rdd.map(lambda x: x).collect()
      for j in month_list:
        print(s3_list[0].j.Month)
        break
      break
```

How this is giving me error. Can someone please tell how to access the column whose name is not fixed. Thanks in advance!

s3_list output looks like: `[Row(product='xxxxx-xxxx', Gender='F', 202005=0, 202006=-1, 202007=2149)]` and j.Month values are `['202005', '202006', '202007']`

Dataframe looks like:
[image]

Also sample values of months is shown in dataframe.

Comment: Could you provide a sample, ie .show() of the dataframe? And are the values of month_list ```['202005', '202006', '202007']```?

Comment: @BrendanA question edited with requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into the same problem, the following code fixed the problem for me.

```
for i in uniqueProduct_list:
   s3_df = channel_Result_8_df.filter((f.col("product") == i.product) & (f.col("S") == 3))
   s3_list =  s3_df.rdd.map(lambda x: x).collect()
   for j in month_list:
     print(s3_list[0].__getitem__(str(j.Month)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the values of a [`Row`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Row.html) using `[]` notation.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row


schema = StructType([StructField('Product', StringType()), StructField('Gender',StringType()), StructField('202111',IntegerType()), StructField('202112',IntegerType()), StructField('202201',IntegerType())])
rows = [Row('xxxxx-xxxx', 'M', 0, 1873, 0)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema)

s3_list = df.collect()

for m in ["202111", "202112", "202201"]:
    print(s3_list[0][m])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, these months values are not fixed. They are coming from another list which I have created by using a dataframe column values. I found the solution and posting it below.